# Does anybody have any multiple choice questions for any of these topics

Tags: financial-economics

I have an exam next week and just trying to find some MCQ to do but cannot find any. These are the topics:

Week 1 The Consumption-based CAPM

Week 2 Risk-Sharing, Portfolio Choice, SDF generalised, portfolio performance

Week 3 SDF and factor models, Factor Model empirics, RVF, Rational Bubbles

Week 4 Time-varying returns, empirics, mean reversion, predictability, volatility

Week 5 Behavioural Finance

cheers

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to be a good fit for the SE format.